# $\pi^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1)$ along $\pi:X=\text{Bl}_p\mathbb{P}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

It might be a silly question, and we are working on the complex field.

Consider the blowing-up $\pi:X=\text{Bl}_p\mathbb{P}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^2$ and the exceptional divisor $E$. Let $H$ be a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^2$, then $\pi^*H$ is a hyperplane if $p\notin H$ or $\pi^*H=E+\tilde{H}$ if $p\in H$. We know that $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1)$ corresponds to a hyperplane $H$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$.

> What is $p^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1)$? It is $\mathcal{O}_{X}(1)$ or $\mathcal{O}_{X}(1)\otimes\mathcal{O}_{X}(E)$?

Comment: That depends on what do you mean by $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$.